# Can we not be charged the -1 for downvoting an answer if the user has no rep?

Tags: feature-request

So here is the situation -

1. A new user sees an empty text box on the Internet and says, "I must contribute!"  Grant you, they haven't read the [about] or really gotten a sense of what the site is, but they must contribute!
2. I review their "answer", offer some kind words of encouragement.  But then I realize I should also be voting them down, because the purpose of reviews is quality after all!
3. So, I vote down, and it gives me a -1.
4. The user, whose reputation cannot go below 1, sees nothing but the big ugly -1.

In other words, I've paid for their mistake.  I understand why, but it doesn't seem fair. Even if somebody upvotes their answer *after* I spent the rep, they get the full +10, and the -2 they should have gotten is null and void. The downvote is still a good signal, but if its not going to cost them anything, I have no incentive to give it.  Indeed, it costs me to send the signal.

There is also a very simple and elegant solution - If the user has only 1 rep, don't charge me for the downvote.

There is even a side benefit - users in the penalty box who deserve downvotes will be able to get them too.  More feedback is good here.

This is a one-line fix.  Could we have it?

Comment: *This is a one line fix*... Of course. `user.upvote += (rainbows, waffles) => {if(rep == 1)unicorn.DoMagicStuff();};`

Comment: Ok, I get it!  People don't like this idea.  Sorry!

Comment: I daresay if *one* reputation point causes enough distress to cause you to open a meta question about it, you might be a little too focused on rep.

Comment: I do enough reviews on C.SE to where it can cost me 5 a day or so... Over the course of a year, that really adds up

Comment: @AffableGeek I've spent thousands of rep on downvotes. I consider it a valuable use of my Imaginary Internet Points.  For me it's the only thing they're good for.

Comment: @Servy We should be able to buy coffee mugs or t-shirt with rep.

Comment: @Servy: Can I have some? ;-)

Comment: @Jamal Sure, you can have some downvotes.  I'm not quite out of votes for the day yet.

Comment: @AffableGeek: [These hats?](http://people.ucsc.edu/~tlreynol/exhibit/tf2.png)

Comment: I was actually thikning [these](http://stackexchange.com/promos/12/winter-bash)

Comment: @AffableGeek: Works for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> it costs me to send the signal

That's exactly right, and *it's intentional*.  It's there so that people think carefully about what they downvote to ensure that it holds the appropriate amount of weight for the person casting it as it does for the person having it cast on them (keep in mind that the negative effects of being downvoted aren't really about the rep; it's the emotional signal that it sends).

Comment: But my reputation is every bit as emotional!

Comment: @AffableGeek Yes...I agree.  That's what makes my first two sentences correct.  If that weren't true this answer would be invalid.

Comment: I actually feel kinda bad about this. My emotional attachment to fake internet points means that I only downvote answers that are *egregiously* bad.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar: I mostly downvote NAAs, but sometimes answers that I *know* are really bad, regardless of my rep.

Comment: It makes me very sad to know that people feel an answer is incorrect or not a good solution to a problem but won't downvote the post.  I just hate seeing several comments explaining why an answer won't work (when it's not a small fix) that don't have downvotes.

Comment: @Servy I'd be a lot less concerned about my internet points if I had +2k. Those privileges are really what I'm holding out for.

Comment: And that is precisely the disincentive I'm trying to avoid..

Comment: @Servy: Fortunately, this doesn't "affect" me as much due to my lack of coding experience (obviously I would only downvote if I'm positive that the answer is bad).  The same applies to other areas, too.

Comment: @AffableGeek I see no difference between 1 rep and non-1 rep users in how they are currently approached by users, or how they *should* be handled by the system.  People are too unwilling to use downvotes in general, not just when dealing with a 1 rep user.

Comment: @Servy fwiw, I downvote the *s#!t* out of questions.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Not according to your profile you don't.  15% of your votes are downvotes.  (Granted, the site wide average is lower still...)

Comment: @Servy that's only because for a long time I didn't know that downvoting questions didn't cost anything. I'm a lot better about that now.

Comment: @Jamal: I'm guessing you want to show how many downvotes you've cast recently, but that information is actually not visible when you look at someone else's reputation page (only when you look at your own).

Comment: @DavidRobinson: The Reputation tab isn't (not just the Votes tab)?  I guess I should've tested that.

Comment: @DavidRobinson I assumed he was trying to show all of the suggested edits, indicating how many posts needed improvement, but that makes a bit more sense.

Comment: @Jamal If that information were shown then you could tell whether someone downvoted a post of yours.

Comment: @Servy: That, too, after thinking about it. :-)

Comment: @Jamal Your total upvotes/downvotes is shown to everyone in the summary though.

Answer (score 18):

A one-line fix? That would complicate the hell out of the reputation system. What if the user is only temporarily at 1 reputation? Maybe they got serially downvoted and it will get reversed. What if the user is currently suspended? This would add a lot more complications to the reputation system than you're imagining.

You shouldn't be thinking of the -1 as a fee to cause damage to another user; it's a fee to *downvote* an answer, simple as that. You're downvoting the answer, and thus you should be charged the fee.

Comment: And if the answer is deleted, you get reimbursed. :-)

Comment: Precisely. I find more often than not, downvoted answers for me, get deleted, and its essentially free.